# User's custom profile fields

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am currently working on a system that would allow users to add additional custom fields for the contacts that they add.

I wondered what is the best and most efficient approach to add such ability?

Right now what I was thinking was to have 1 table per users (with foreign keys to a "main" contacts table) and then adding a column for each custom fields that the user adds (since I don't expect to have more then 100-200 users per database shards [sharding is easy since every users never see each-other's content in this system]), although I am not 100% sure that this would be the right solution for such problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could try to have one separated table to store a reference to the user, plus the field name and value, this way you will be able to have lots of custom fields.

Comment: This is the other alternative I was thinking about. Although I'm wondering, what are the performance implications of such thing if I want to add the ability to search through these fields with such method?

Comment: I don't think it will be a problem if you index it though the user reference, since it can be a simple index (if you use a simple primary key field for users) and it will probably be the only search type.

Comment: Anyway, it would be better to have this kind of search than in 100 field in 1 table

Comment: It's actually 1 table per users with it's custom fields as columns only in his table that I was thinking about.

Comment: I think I'll go with what you've suggested. Seems quite logic to implement. I'll keep the question opened so I can see if there is any other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

If you go with [Boyce-Codd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form), you separate the information and store them into a table.
Means one table for all users with a foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

One table per user would lead to hundreds or more tables with possible repeated information.

You need to have one table named USERS that stores the id of a user and fixed info you might want. Then, you could have a CONTACT table, that stores the type of contact user might create, and one matching table USER_CONTACT that matches the user unique id with the id of the contact that was created.

With this, you could have advanced data mining on all the information stored, like nowing how many contacts each user created, who created more, etc...

Comment: That is exactly what it is right now. I need to add a way for the users to add custom fields into the lot.